# Is there an AspectJ pointcut expression that searches all subpackages?

Tags: java, expression, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

So I've got an aspect with a method declared with the following expression:

```
@Before("execution(* aaa.bbb.ccc.*.*(..))")
```

This works perfectly for all classes in the package `aaa.bbb.ccc`.  Now, however, I would like to capture all classes in `aaa.bbb`, *including* those in `aaa.bbb.ccc`.  So I tried backing it up to here:

```
@Before("execution(* aaa.bbb.*.*(..))")
```

This only grabs the classes from `aaa.bbb`, though, and ignores classes from `aaa.bbb.ccc`.  Is there a way I can make the expression search for all subpackages recursively?

Answer (score 23):

Got it!  The textual change is surprisingly trivial.

```
@Before("execution(* aaa.bbb.*.*(..))")
```

... becomes ...

```
@Before("execution(* aaa.bbb..*.*(..))")
```

Simply add the extra period between the package name and the qualifier, and you're off to the races.

One issue I encountered after making the change was that all of Spring blew up and crashed on me.  That was because the aspect *itself* was in a subpackage of `aaa.bbb`.  So if you do this, make sure you use a `!within` clause to exempt your aspect from trying to process itself.

Comment: This is basic stuff well covered in the documentation. Anyway, nice that you found it by yourself. You can optimise it by omitting one dot and one star: `execution(* aaa.bbb..*(..))`

Comment: @kriegaex Could you point me to the documentation where this is?  I searched on Google for quite awhile before I came and asked here.

Comment: Look under "type name patterns" in the [Programming Guide](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/printable.html#d0e5901).

Comment: You can also search for the string `..*` in order to find references in the [AspectJ 5 Developer's Notebook](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/printable.html), the [Development Environment Guide](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/printable.html) and the [FAQ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/faq.html). I admit that most mentions are rather indirect, but the one from my previous comment is explicit, though maybe not easy to find.

Comment: The syntax pattern is also mentioned in the [Spring AOP documentation, section "Examples"](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-examples).